# How I do pack JAXB 2.3.3 with my open source programme?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, java

I wrote a little java programme in Java 8 that uses a lot JAXB stuff that I ship as a free JAR, licensed under GPL.

Users that have installed Java 9/10 installed need to use jvm parameters to run it. Users that have installed Java 11+ cannot run it "out of the box".
To make Java 8 to 15 users happy, I'd like to include the necessary JAXB jars with it. I searched and tried JAXB RI 2.3.3 from the Eclipse Jakarta project.

Locally, I tried to pack three JAXB-JARs into my jar and got it running under Java 11 and 12 after a few modifications in `MANIFEST.MF`: `jaxb-impl.jar`, `jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar`, and `jakarta.activation.jar`. Those seem to be binary-only...

Can I ship it that way or does that violate GPL or Eclipse Jakarta JAXB's License (EPL1)?

To ask more specificly: Do I have to put all JARs from JAXB-RI into it even if the programme doesn't need them? Do I have to put their source codes into it as well (if yes: where can I find them?)?

Thanks!